# Bash scripting: weird issue when running a background process using su -c

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, process

I have a very strange problem, in my terminal, if I load my binary this way:

```
adb shell "su -c '
chmod 666 /dev/graphics/fb0
&& export CLASSPATH=/data/local/device.jar
&& export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local
&& exec app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main /data/local/device.conf'"
```

Then the binary loads fine but it is foreground process, and adb shell doesn't return until I kill the program, obviously.

Now here is the weird thing, if I want to app_process as a background process and add & at the end:

```
&& exec app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main /data/local/device.conf &'"
```

It looks like it terminates immediately. I tried adding a sleep:

```
adb shell "su -c '
chmod 666 /dev/graphics/fb0
&& export CLASSPATH=/data/local/device.jar
&& export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local
&& exec app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main /data/local/device.conf & && sleep 50'"
```

The program runs for 50 seconds, but after that, adb shell returns to the command line and the program is terminated. (my program has a while (true) loop waiting for a socket connection, so it will never terminate).

No error is getting generated or anything. During the 50 seconds of sleep, if I do adb shell and ps, I see "app_process", but after 50, it is not there anymore, and my command line is back to receiving input on my computer.

I am really not sure what is going on. It looks like running as a background process makes "su" return to adb's shell, the shell quits, and the program terminates. If this is the case, how could I please fix it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual answer for problems like this is to use `nohup(1)` and redirect stdin, stdout, and stderr to avoid leaving any descriptors open to the terminal. Try this:

```
exec nohup app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main\
/data/local/device.conf >/tmp/out 2>/tmp/err </dev/null &
```

Comment: With a sleep I actually get this: /data/local/device.conf >/tmp/out 2>/tmp/err </dev/null & && sleep 5'"
cannot create /tmp/out: directory nonexistent

Comment: I changed to /data/out/ but know it doesn't find the class anymore (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:). Could it be that nohup changes the CLASSPATH please?

Comment: It did not like the \ for some reason. Now it works but I still need a sleep otherwise it doesn't load. But it works forever, even after the sleep:

Comment: adb shell "su -c '
chmod 666 /dev/graphics/fb0
&& export CLASSPATH=/data/local/device.jar
&& export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local
&& exec nohup app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main /data/local/device.conf >/data/tmp/out 2>/data/tmp/err </dev/null & && sleep 5'"

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I just put in the backslash because I hate horizontal scrollbars here -- and to line-wrap a shell command, you've got to escape the newline. If you're putting it all on one line, go ahead and ignore that backslash. :) The `nohup` shouldn't modify your environment variables, it just fiddles with the default disposition of the `HUP` (hangup) signal.

Comment: Also the shell never returns because of the sleep. Without the sleep it does (but the program does not get loaded). If I do control-c though, the program keeps running as a background process.

Comment: Hrm. That's surprising... Once the sleep is over, I'd expect the shell to return.

Comment: It's almost perfect sarnold, thanks. I don't know why the program does not load or terminates without the sleep. With the sleep it does, but then the shell does not terminate unless I use crtl+c. The program runs as a background process now.

Comment: I tried changing the sleep to 0 and it has also the same behavior.

Comment: Would the sleep not get executed? I know app_process is run as a background but maybe it actually wait for it to finish before executing the sleep? It sounds to me like the only explanation.

Comment: If I do adb kill on app_process, the script terminates (so sleep 0 gets executed).

Comment: Hrm, I think the problem might be with the `& &&` -- try just a single `& sleep 1`. I think `& &&` might be triggering a shell syntax error.

Comment: It's doing the same thing, weirdly.

Comment: Hrm. You might want to uncheck my answer, if it isn't completely solved -- that way someone else might still come in with The Solution. If it is marked Solved, then it is less likely someone else will give an answer.

Comment: If I replace sleep 1 or sleep 0 with an echo "test", the program terminates immediately but it doesn't run as a background process.

Comment: Ok, thanks sarnold. You helped me a lot though, I least I am having the result I wanted (although some side effect: script not terminating) and an added sleep which is weird. Thank you very much.

Comment: I figured out why I needed the sleep. I also needed nohup in front of su! The shell does not terminate though, but I was able to get rid of the sleep 1!

Comment: $ADB shell "nohup su -c '
chmod 666 /dev/graphics/fb0
&& export CLASSPATH=/data/local/device.jar
&& export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local
&& exec nohup app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main /data/local/device.conf' >/data/tmp/out 2>/data/tmp/err </dev/null"

Comment: I still have to crtl-c in the shell to terminate the script, but it's a lot better now!

Comment: If you add the `&` at the end of the string: `</dev/null" &`, chances are good you'll get your shell prompt back quickly.

Comment: It's weird, the application does not start at all when I add the & after /dev/null. I am not sure why.